# xcode 4 - Date picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, datepicker

is there a way to have the date picker smaller or with different size?

I have been trying to make it small programatically but it seems like there is no luck.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you cannot

if you want you may customize your own date picker using pickerview

Date picker is not customizable.

Comment: True, however when using AutoLayout I have noticed the DatePicker able to shrink down to 3 rows. Would be great if you could choose 3/5 row option as default.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of time you could create your own UIView object (with your custom background) with one (or more, better if configurable) UITableView scrolling-paged inside (and other object, like the light blue indicator) and show this UIView inside a UIActionSheet (you will get animation in/out for free).

It's not a easy solution, but it is.

If you'll create this component, any code released open source is really appreciated.